# Return struct created from new struct within function

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, new-operator

In this code, does the array pointer in the struct returned from the function point to the same block of memory that was defined with the new struct?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

struct Arr
{
    const int Col;
    const int Row;
    double* CAR{ new double[Col * Row] };
    Arr(int y, int x) : Col(x), Row(y) {}
    void Del() { delete[] CAR; }
    int Indx(int y, int x) { return (x + y * Col); }
    int Size() { return Col * Row; }
    void Print(std::string title);
};
void Arr::Print(std::string title)
{
    std::cout << title << '\n';
    for (int I = 0; I < Row; I++)
    {
        for (int In = 0; In < Col; In++)
        {
            std::cout << CAR[Indx(I, In)] << " / ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
const Arr retfunc(std::string h, Arr& a, Arr& b)
{
    Arr* temp = NULL;
    if (h == "Had") 
    {
        temp = new Arr(a.Row, a.Col);
        for (int I = 0; I < a.Row; I++)
        {
            for (int In = 0; In < a.Col; In++)
            {
                temp->CAR[temp->Indx(I, In)] = a.CAR[a.Indx(I, In)] * b.CAR[b.Indx(I, In)];
            }
        }
    } Arr T = *temp; return T;
}

int main()
{
    int val = 5;
    Arr a(2, 2);
    Arr b(2, 2);
    for (int I = 0; I < 2; I++)
    {
        for (int In = 0; In < 2; In++)
        {
            a.CAR[a.Indx(I, In)] = 10.0 / val + In;
            b.CAR[b.Indx(I, In)] = 8.0 / val + In;
        }
    }
    a.Print("a");
    b.Print("b");
    Arr S = retfunc("Had", a, b);
    S.Print("S");   
    S.Del();
}
```

So essentially then, does calling delete on S clear the same memory that was allocated in retfunc?

Comment: When you do `double* CAR{ new double[Col * Row] };` what is the values of `Col` and `Row`? Hint: Their values have not been set yet...

Comment: They get set in the constructor, unless im not doing it right?

Comment: They get set in the constructor, but too late!

Comment: @Yugenswitch That happens *after* `CAR` has been initialized.

Comment: There is no reason for using `new` in `retfunc`. (And you're leaking that object, too, and possibly dereferencing a null pointer.)

Comment: so I should move the constructor above?

Comment: You should implement the `new` in the constructor.

Comment: Just put the `new` in the constructor initializer list. Or better yet, use `std::vector<double>` instead.

Comment: the function normally has many different matrix operations that can be defined by the string, some operations produce different sizes. thats why I'm using new. is this incorrect?

Comment: I see, so then that means when I assign *temp to T, CAR does not create ask for more memory?

Comment: @Damien _They get set in the constructor, but too late!_ I don't think so (but was not quite sure). Hence, I tried in g++ 10.2: [**Demo in coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4820d2bcb95430b). According to this, it seems to work to override default-initialized members in the constructor, and they still will be considered in default initialization of other members. (I admit that a demo is not yet a proof...)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I tested that code in MSVC and debug mode, and was amazed that MSVC processes it correctly: it assigns the members in declaration order, so `Col` and `Row` are indeed initialized before being used for `CAR` initialization. The code is still a recipe for memory leaks but initialization seems correct at least for MSVC (not tested with other compilers)

Comment: @Scheff and Serge I feel a language-lawyer question coming up... :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I won't add the tag on this question :-)

Comment: @Scheff: WIth `constexpr`, you ensure no UBs, so that [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f853a07a2afdb45) is a proof (unless compiler bug ;-) ).

Comment: @Scheff Interesting indeed. I may be wrong from the lawyer point of view. But personnaly, I would avoid such construction ...:)

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function `retfunc` has a memory leak because the object `temp` dynamically allocated within the function is not freed.

As the class does not have an explicit copy constructor then in this declaration

```
Arr T = *temp
```

there is used member-wise copying of data members of the object temp to the object T. The value of the pointer CAR of the object temp will be copied in the pointer CAR of the object T and will be a valid pointer due to the life-time of the dynamically allocated object `temp`.

When within a class there is dynamically allocated memory then you need to write an explicit destructor, copy constructors for lvalues and rvalues and  copy assignment operators for lvalues and rvalues.

Comment: thats what I thought, but I was thinking maybe because CAR is a pointer, when the pointer from temp gets copied to S and then S to T, does that not mean it is just copying the memory address?

Comment: @Yugenswitch that is correct, the pointer is copied. But what about the object `temp` itself?

Comment: ah awesome! so if i just delete temp then no memory leak?

Comment: If my tests are correct, the main problem is the missing `return *temp` at the end of `retfunc` (apart for code being a recipe for memory leaks because the allocated block is not released in dtor, and of the rule of 5)

Comment: input is much appreciated!  very noob at pointers still.

Comment: @Yugenswitch: if you are a beginner, avoid manual allocation in ctror, or respect the rule of 5, to automatically release it in destructor, and handle it in copy or move operations. There are corner cases so if you go that way, show your first working code on CodeReview.

Answer (score 0):

You should just have a `return *temp` at the end of `retfunc` which is declared to return an `Arr` object. Once this is fixed, `S.Del()` correctly releases the memory block allocated in `retfunc`.

Yet this is terrible code. You fail to release the blocs allocated in `a` and `b` object. Not an error because the end of the program will release them, but this is a recipe for memory leaks. Moreover, you have a manual allocated memory block in constructor, but no explicit copy constructor nor assignment operator. If you write:

```
Arr c = a;
```

both c and a will share the same `CAR` array which may or not be what you want.

Long story short, I think that this is not a blatant error but at least an antipattern.